coverpoint at_least option is not catching in simulator causes missing of bins
I am writing a cross coverpoint for a unique case where I have to set option.at_least=0.
    test_atleast_cp: cross signal_a_1bit, signal_b_1bit {
      option.at_least = 0;
    }

I am expecting that all the 4 bins are 100% covered for this this cross but the questa visualizer shows the following

I am using Questa tool for simulation
//  Questa Sim-64
//  Version 2024.2 linux_x86_64 May 20 2024

The cross is between more than two signals which causes lots of combination. I want to cover some of them and ignore others. But i want to see that which of the other combinations have hits for analysis purpose (visually). But for this we should have bins but these bins should not be the missed one (to save coverage numbers) so setting at_least = 0.

The IEEE 1800-2023 SystemVerilog LRM is not clear about the behavior of setting the at_least counter to 0. In most other places, setting a counter limit to 0 means don't count or unlimited. Try setting the option weight to 0 instead.
